# Environmental variable or function in DiscriminatorMap annotation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

#### How can I have a discriminator map that's set based on the current environment?

I have an entity using single-table inheritance with a discriminator column:

`@ORM\DiscriminatorMap({1="Product", 2="User"})`

The discriminator values (`1, 2`) differ in my production and development environments, so the values need to be dynamically set. Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be an option in the [Doctrine annotation documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.6/custom.html#enumerated-values).

Using an environmental directly in the annotation doesn't seem to work. For example, I have tried:

```
@ORM\DiscriminatorMap('%discrimination_array%')
```

and then defining `discrimination_array` in `doctrine.yaml`:

```
discrimination_array: '{%env(PRODUCT)%="Product", %env(USER)%="User"}'
```

along with corresponding environmental vars in `.env`:

```
PRODUCT=1
USER=2
```

However, Doctrine throws errors like

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%env(PRODUCT)%' to data type smallint.

Is it possible to set the class discrimination map based on the current environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by extending data mapping for a specific entity. When the annotations are being parsed, Doctrine [fires an event](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#load-classmetadata-event):

> When the mapping information for an entity is read, it is populated in to a ClassMetadataInfo instance. You can hook in to this process and manipulate the instance.

By subscribing to this event, it's possible to set the Entity's `DiscriminatorMap` after the Entity has been loaded.

Here's a general example. First, implement a subscriber. On loading the relevant Entity (`Item::class`), add the relevant `DiscriminatorMap`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\Listener;

use App\Entity\Item;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

class LoadClassMetadataSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $discriminatorMap;

    public function __construct( $discriminatorMap)
    {
        $this->discriminatorMap = $discriminatorMap;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::loadClassMetadata
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata $classMetadata
         */
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        if ($classMetadata->name !== Item::class) {
            return;
        }

        $map = [];
        foreach ($this->discriminatorMap as $value) {
            $partial = explode('=', $value);
            $map[$partial[0]] = $partial[1];
        }

        $classMetadata->setDiscriminatorMap($map);
    }
}
```

Because the discriminator map is added *after* the class has been parsed, `Entity\Item` does not need a `DiscriminatorMap` annotation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Map;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(...)
 * @ORM\Table(...)
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 */
abstract class Item {
```

The mapping should be added to the environment (`.env` or similar):

```
DISCRIMINATOR_MAP=one=App\Entity\Item\One,two=App\Entity\Item\Two
```

Register the subscriber to the correct event (`config/services.yaml`):

```
services:
    ...

    # Set up the custom subscriber. It'll take the environmental variable as
    # an argument, and subscribe to the `loadClassMetadata` event. 
    App\Doctrine\Listener\LoadClassMetadataSubscriber:
        public: true
        arguments:
            - '%env(csv:MAP)%'
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: loadClassMetadata, lazy: true }
```

Comment: This looks like it's extending the Doctrine 'loadMetadata' system, and explicitly setting the metadata for a specific class? I hadn't thought of that, so thanks! :) This answer's good, but could be improved by a bit more explanation of what it's doing and why. Do you mind if I edit it after I implement?

Comment: Yes, this code extends data mapping for a specific entity. You can take this code as a basis and use it for your own purposes.

Comment: <3 nice way for decoupling logic from parent